# Getting claws-mail to work under Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, email, upgrade

A few hours ago I (perhaps unwisely) upgraded my Ubuntu OS from version 20.04 to 22.04.  The upgrade seemed to go OK, but now my email client, claws mail, will not run.  This distresses me, since I rely heavily on claws-mail.

I invoked claws-mail from the command line, so as to be able to see error messages, and got:

```
(claws-mail:66186): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:33:53.577: Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
**
Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /usr/share/icons/mate/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unable to load image-loading module: /usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 5)
Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /usr/share/icons/mate/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unable to load image-loading module: /usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 5)
Abort (core dumped)
```

I am afraid that this means little or nothing to me.  Can anyone give me any gentle guidance as to what I might do to remedy the situation?

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the error message

```
     unable to load image-loading module: /usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

we see the key phrase

```
"cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

which means that something is missing that is needed in order to display the PNG image file "image-missing.png"

If you do an

```
   ls -Fl  /usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
```

does it show a directory listing for that file or say "no such file or directory"?

If that file does exist (hopefully it being missing is the problem) then it would mean that libpng12.so.0 is missing which would be rather more complicated because it is looking for the specific version 12  of libpng and that is not the one available for your upgraded version of Ubuntu.  In which case you would need to remove just the claws-mail option PLUGIN package (not the base claws-mail) which requires that version of libpng.

Buy if it the simpler latter case, then that means that that image loader shared library file is missing from your system and you need to install the package that contains that file.

If in a terminal you then do

```
   apt  search  libgdk-pixbuf
```

you will get a list of package names (in green) including one for just GDK Pixbuf library.

This will be of the form libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-{some_version}

You will then need to do with root privileges (ie using sudo or logged in as root)

```
       apt install libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-{some_version}
```

replacing some_vesion with the actual version number and possibly text such as ubuntu (indicating that it is package built by Ubuntu with attributes or dependencies specific to Ubuntu).

The easiest it to just copy and paste the text in green on the line above only the text "GDK Pixbuf library"

Or if you want to do it in a graphical user interface, fire up your graphical user interface to the package manager and search through all the libraries for the package matching the name which will take far longer than just doing the commands above in a terminal.)

During your system upgrade, this package was probably not installed because none of your packages has a hard dependency on it, and probably only one of the optional plugins for claws-mail requires it as seen by the error message above.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I may at last be getting somewhere, but I'm not out of the woods yet. When I execute your "ls -F1 ..." command I get "-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 77072 Aug 26 2020 /usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so*" so the file is there. (The less simple case.) If I understand you correctly, this indicates that I need to unload the "claws-mail option PLUGIN package". I don't actually understand what this means. Can you please explain more, and guide me as to how to effect this removal? Thanks. –